# Need help gleaning data from several mysql tables into one php table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four MySQL tables, each created by a CMS, thus the information I need is spread out across them. Also, there is not one ID to thread them with, which makes this task more complicated. Basically, I need to get sales tax amount from one table (it has its own ID), promotional amounts (it has its own ID), and the order no and date (it, too, has its own ID). The only connection is the fourth table called order_reports, which contains all three IDs (although they are not named the same).

As I'm an intermediate MySQL/php developer, I can't seem to figure out the correct sequence and commands. I've tried Left Join, Full Join, Union, Case..., etc.

Basically, here's what I've got, which renders a blank. I have verified connection, so I know that's not the issue:

```
SELECT  tax_id, tax_amount, promo_id, promo_amount,  order_id, order_no, order_date, order_report_id, report_id
FROM sales_tax, promotions, order_reports, orders 
WHERE sales_tax.tax_id = order_reports.report_id AND promotions.promo_id = order_reports.report_id AND order_reports.order_report_id = order.order_id
```

---

sales_tax table:

```
tax_id       tax_amount
200             1.95
202             3.15
204             2.95
206             4.05
208             1.95
```

---

promotions table:

```
promo_id       promo_amount
201                 -4.00
207                 -3.50
```

---

order_reports table:

```
report_id          report_type         order_report_id
200                   sales_tax               101
201                   promotions              102
202                   sales_tax               102
204                   sales_tax               103
206                   sales_tax               104
207                   promotions              105
208                   sales_tax               105
```

---

orders:

```
order_id        order_no          order_date (converted ISO)
101                 HS506              07-01-2019
102                 HS507              07-02-2019
103                 HS508              07-05-2019
104                 HS509              07-06-2019
105                 HS510              07-08-2019
```

Here's what I'd like:

```
Date           Order No.         Sales Tax Amount    Promotion Amount 
07-01-2019        HS506              1.95
07-02-2019        HS507               3.15               -4.00                         
07-05-2019        HS508               2.95
07-06-2019        HS509               4.05               -4.00
07-08-2019        HS510               1.95
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I can do for you. You can either loop through the results in php or add more conditions to the query to display your desired output. It's up to you.

```
SELECT order_date, order_no, sales_tax.tax_amount, promotions.promo_amount   
FROM orders 
JOIN order_reports ON orders.order_id = order_reports.order_report_id
LEFT JOIN sales_tax ON order_reports.report_id = sales_tax.tax_id
LEFT JOIN promotions ON order_reports.report_id = promotions.promo_id 
ORDER BY order_date
```

[image]